# How to create patch for staged files with Magit

Tags: emacs, patch, magit

How could I create patch for staged files with Magit?

I tried "W p", when prompt "Format range or commit(master)", I am not sure what should I put there, I tried HEAD..master, but it doesn't create any patch.

I tried command line: "git diff --cached > my.patch" create what I expected.

How could I create the same patch with Magit?

Comment: I have opened an issue for this: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2950.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magit uses [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) (see which for more information) to create patches<sup>1</sup>, and consequently requires the changes in question to have been committed.

So commit your staged changes, then create your patch based on HEAD.

Note that the metadata for the commit will be used to populate the patch headers.

If you don't want to keep the commit, then simply soft-reset back to `HEAD^` (you can type <kbd>x</kbd> at that previous commit).

<sup>1</sup> Note that this patch format is *different* to the plain `git diff` output, and must be applied with [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) rather than `git apply`. At present magit only supports patch files in the `format-patch` format.

You can still run arbitrary git commands without leaving magit, if you need to create or apply an unformatted patch file. Type <kbd>!</kbd> for the appropriate menu.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't found a way to create a patch directly, you can certainly make a patch from any diff file!

From `magit-diff`, you can run <kbd>W</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd>, or `magit-patch-save` to save the diff as a patch. You can customise your diff so that the patch matches just the changes you wish to share.